# requested source is not available in Spring MVC when using @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC I have problem with loading `.jsp` page when using `@RequstMapping`. The handler method responds but `.jsp` page can't load because I don't know why the `ModelAndView` adds something in string that represents URL path. Here is the code in `@Controller` class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sent/{phoneNumber}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showSentMessagesToSelectedPhoneNumber(@PathVariable int phoneNumber,HttpSession session)
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("sentMessagesToPhoneNumber");
            ...
            return modelAndView;
     }
```

Here is what I have in `.jsp`:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sent/${reciever.getPhoneNumber()}.html">${reciever.getContactName()}</a>
```

Then when I click on the ling the browser tells me:
`HTTP Status 404 - /HomeWork/sent/WEB-INF/pages/sentMessagesToPhoneNumber.jsp`.
As I can conclude is that `/sent` in `@RequestMapping` is add to the path.
Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: can you post your servlet-config.xml?

Comment: Where is that servlet-config.xml? I only have app-config.xml which I created.

Comment: it is the same thing, can you post it?

Comment: I posted my app-context.xml file!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have defined a `view resolver` in your config file. Something like

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
              value="someViewClass"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

When you construct a `ModelAndView` in the controller with a name, you are directed to a jsp page with the prefix and suffix defined in the bean and the name. You get a 404 maybe because you don't have `sentMessagesToPhoneNumber.jsp` in `/WEB-INF/pages/` directory.

Comment: I have all this, but the problem isn't that I haven't `sentMessagesToPhoneNumber.jsp` in '/WEB-INF/pages/'. The problem is that when i click on the link, don't know what adds that `/sent' in the path where 'ModelAndView' object searches for resource.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact problem, but I came across [this java doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html). I think it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have in my app-context.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mk.ukim.finki.mp.homework"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />

    <import resource="security-context.xml"/>
```